# Possible to use a symlink, junction, or similar to make one folder mirrored to multiple locations on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, symbolic-link

I have surveillance camera software that saves to a particular directory on a PC.  I'd like to be able to somehow make any files saved to this folder simultaneously save to both the original folder, and a mapped drive / network location.  The idea is somewhat of an instant backup in a remote location, in case the main system were to be stolen.

I'd like to avoid actual sync software if possible because it seems like unnecessary overhead.

It seems like there should be some way to use something kind of similar to a symlink, or some sort of tee'd junction, to make this folder actually mirrored in 2 places.  Is that possible?